# using github for windows can't start rails server after pulling a repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ruby-on-rails-4, github-for-windows

I added some collaborators to a rails project on github. They pull down the project using github for windows but then cannot start the rails server

`rails server` gives them the same output as typing `rails`

When we do `ls` we get:

[image]

From the Github directory I tried `chmod -R 777 sindika` but it didn't work. Why can't they pull down the project and start the server?

Comment: What is the error message they get when running `rails server` ... Did they try running `bundle exec rails server`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the version of your globally installed `rails` gem is different from the one the project is built on, so Rails don't recognize this folder as its project. Doing `bundle && bundle exec rails s` should do the trick. Another way to solve this would be to uninstall the current version of the Rails gem and install the one that corresponds to your project.